# Can I have koa-static serve assets at a custom (e.g., /static/) path?

Tags: node.js, static-files, koa

The docs at https://github.com/koajs/static and my personal experience trying out koa-static lead me to believe that you can **only** serve files from the root URL of your app.

For example:

```
app.use(serve('./some/dir/'));
```

Given the above use of `serve`, the URL to access a file `./some/dir/something.txt` would be `localhost:3000/something.txt`. There doesn't seem to be a way to configure my app such that the same file (and all other files in the same dir) is served at `localhost:3000/static/something.txt` instead.

I'm new to Node and to Koa, so I've just begun to dive into this and I'm probably missing something really obvious.

#### I tried using koa-route to achieve this:

```
app.use(route.get('/static/*'), serve(__dirname + '/some/dir'));
```

But upon requesting `/static/something.txt` I was met with the following:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/example/src/node_modules/koa-route/index.js:34:18)
      at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.next (native)
      at onFulfilled (/Users/me/example/src/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:64:19)
      at /Users/me/example/src/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:53:5
      at Object.co (/Users/me/example/src/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:49:10)
      at Object.toPromise (/Users/me/example/src/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:117:63)
      at next (/Users/me/example/src/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:98:29)
      at onFulfilled (/Users/me/example/src/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:68:7)
      at /Users/me/example/src/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:53:5
      at Object.co (/Users/me/example/src/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:49:10)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To relocate middleware to another part of your app url-wise, you can use `koa-mount`.

```
'use strict';
const koa = require('koa');
const mount = require('koa-mount');

const app = koa();
app.use(function* () { this.body = 'Hello, world'; });
app.use(mount('/foo', function*() { this.body = 'Hello, foo'; }));

app.listen(3000);

curl localhost:3000
> 'Hello, world'
curl localhost:3000/foo
> 'Hello, foo'
```

`koa-router` itself [does not support regex paths or parameter matching](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router/issues/127).

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. I'm talking about serving at a custom URL path from my own app, not from an external resource. IOW, I want to serve static files from my own, but from a `/static/` path (vs the root).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I answered before you edited your question, and have modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've probably saved me 3 more miserable hours. I'm surprised the only way to achieve this (presumably) is by creating a separate app and mounting it this way (requires reregistering logging and other middleware), but it works perfectly.

Comment: `mount` works on any middleware (precisely, it works on a generator function) not necessarily a separate koa app (which just happens to also be a generator function). You could combine middleware using `koa-compose` and `mount` that instead.

Comment: I tried `app.use(mount('/static', serve(__dirname + '/static')));` (works perfectly) because koa-compose hasn't been updated in quite some time. I'll probably stick with a second app though, so that I can use many middleware.

Comment: you only need koa-compose if you are composing multiple middleware together (also, it hasn't been updated in a long time because it is a very very tiny module, there's not much *to* update)

Answer (score 13):

Sure you can. And as the accepted answer says, the trick is using koa-mount along with koa-static. Though I don't understand why he doesn't provide an example with actual static files. This works for me (in Koa2):

```
.use(serve('public'))
.use(mount('/static', serve('static')))
```

Both folders (public and static) are in my project's root. But the first one is served when the user access to `/`, whereas the second one is served when they go to `/static`.
That's all.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [koa-static-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-static-folder). if you're still interested.

Comment: How would you use koa-static-folder to serve at a custom path?