# Koa - error, file not found - when html and css are in different folders

Tags: javascript, file, server, path, koa

I am not able to set simple Koa server, so it would allow me to have index.html and css files in different folders. Also as next step i want to have many js files in different folders. I do not know Koa. Please be so kind to provide help.

I have tried to use mount as shown in [Can I have koa-static serve assets at a custom (e.g., /static/) path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369227/can-i-have-koa-static-serve-assets-at-a-custom-e-g-static-path) but it did not work

```
const path = require('path');
const Koa = require('koa');
const koaStatic = require('koa-static');
const getPort = require('get-port');

async function runServer() {
    const port = await getPort({ port: 3000 });

    const app = new Koa();
    app.use(koaStatic(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src/static')));
    app.use(koaStatic(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src/styles')));

    app.listen(port);

    console.log(`server started at http://localhost:${port}/`);
}

runServer().catch(console.error);
```

I got following error: GET http://localhost:3000/src/styles/vendor.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

My file structure is as follow:
MyProject ->

```
src-> components (header.component.js, footer.component.js)
src-> services (service.js)
src-> assets (data.json)
src-> scripts (some-js-files.js)
src-> styles (styles.css)
src-> static (index.html)
```

I expect the app to work on localhost:3000 and recognize all paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following your example I have created an dummy project with following structure.

```
~/src -
 | - static
 | - styles
     |- index.html
     |- vendor.css
~/server.js
```

Note that `server.js` is not in the `src` folder, they are on the same level 
And here is the adjusted server code, which is the same as yours except `path.join` part

```
const path = require('path');
const Koa = require('koa');
const koaStatic = require('koa-static');
const getPort = require('get-port');

async function runServer() {
  const port = await getPort({ port: 3000 });

  const app = new Koa();
  app.use(koaStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'src/static')));
  app.use(koaStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'src/styles')));

  app.listen(port);

  console.log(`server started at http://localhost:${port}/`);
}
runServer().catch(console.error);
```

I have noticed that I could access `vendor.css` by typing the following url

http://localhost:45551/vendor.css

In order to have it working I have adjusted this line

```
app.use(koaStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));
```

which exposes all `src` folders and files, so this way I could access the `styles/vendor.css` file by using the following url

http://localhost:33717/styles/vendor.css